# liftweb mapper - setting table name in lower case

Tags: scala, lift

Is it possible to force liftweb mapper use table name in lower case for querying models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a uniform way of generating your table and column names, you should set the MapperRules.{tableName,columnName} PartialFunctions.  So, if you want all of your tables and columns to be snake case, include the following two lines in your Boot.scala file:

```
MapperRules.tableName = (_, name) => StringHelpers.snakify(name)
MapperRules.columnName = (_, name) => StringHelpers.snakify(name)
```

This avoids the extraneous boilerplate of overriding the dbTableName on each class.

Answer (score 7):

You can override dbTableName in your MetaMapper

```
object ModelClass extends ModelClass with LongKeyedMetaMapper {
    override def dbTableName = "model_class"
}
```